# how do I pass a var including the quotes("")

Tags: python

I have the following code where the var has couple of numbers,i need to pass this var to changes option as below and command should be as shown below,i tried the below,can anyone suggest the proper way to do this?

```
def main():
    var = "735531 12345"

    call("tool.exe changes=%s " ,shell=True)
    #command should be run as follows
    #tool.exe changes="735531 12345"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Place the `%s` in double quotes and use single quotes to create the string literal:

```
call('tool.exe changes="%s"' % var, shell=True)
```

See a deomstration below:

```
>>> var = "735531 12345"
>>> '"%s"' % var
'"735531 12345"'
>>> print '"%s"' % var
"735531 12345"
>>>
```

Comment: how do I capture the output (stdout ,stderr)of the call command?

Answer (score 1):

Use the backslash to escape quotes:

```
call("tool.exe changes=\"{0}\"".format(var), shell=True)
```

Comment: how do I capture the output (stdout ,stderr)of the call command?

Answer (score 1):

If you are accepting input var from anywhere outside your program you must first escape var before passing it to the shell. This will prevent commands inside var from owning your boxes.

```
var="1234;rm -rf filename"
subprocess.call("tool.exe %s"%pipes.quote(var),shell=True)
```